# Can't align menu items to the right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align the menu items to the right, but it doesn't work. I think this is because I've used the `float:left` to display the menu horizontal in the right order. I can't fix this problem so I'm asking for help.

A demo of my problem can be found at http://elexode.nl

This is my CSS:

```
/* RESET */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/* OWN CONTENT */

body { 
    background:url('bg.jpg') fixed no-repeat;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

#padding-inline {
    padding:10px 0;
}

.container {
    background:white;
}

.nav-menu {
    height:47px;
}

.nav-menu ul {
    line-height:47px;
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.nav-menu li {
    display:inline;
}

.nav-menu ul li a {
    float:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#5C5C5C;
    padding:0 5px;
}

.nav-menu ul li a:hover {
    color:#000000;
}
```

Comment: Please show your HTML code as well.

Answer (score 0):

change float to right

```
nav-menu a {
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    float: right;
}
```

and change the order of the links:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href='index.html'>VIDEOS</a></li>
    <li><a href='index.html'>MUSIC</a></li>
    <li><a href='index.html'>BIO</a></li>
    <li><a href='index.html'>HOME</a></li>
</ul>
```

and you didnt close the anchor tag... You should close it.

And since you have just started creating the website, I suggest you try using some css-frameworks, such as Foudation 5 http://foundation.zurb.com .

It will help you create responsive websites quite easily. and it supports several navigation styles. Check the docs http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/

Comment: Very Useful, but if I use this theme on my Wordpress theme, how can I change the order of the menu then?

Comment: I didnt understand you question. Which theme are you referring to by "this theme" ?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the link and looks like your html is broken: why is there `<a>` after every `<li>`?

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">
           HOME</a>
    </li>
      <a href="index.html"> </a>
    <li><a href="index.html"></a><a href="index.html">BIO</a></li><a href="index.html">
                    </a><li><a href="index.html"></a><a href="index.html">MUSIC</a></li><a href="index.html">
                    </a><li><a href="index.html"></a><a href="index.html">VIDEOS</a></li><a href="index.html">
                </a></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you just want to shift the HOME MUSIC BIO VIDEOS farther to the right?

I played with just adding a margin to the ul.

```
.nav-menu {
    height: 47px;
    margin-left: 80px;
}
```

But I'm not sure that's what you're looking for.